# One project\solution in two different TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I would like to share a project\solution with two teams, ideally on two TFS.
The option to have both teams using the same TFS doesn't work, because both teams don't have access to one of the TFS and hosting the solution on this TFS is a requirement.

It looks as follows:

Project\solution -> Team1 -> TFS1 (requirement)

Same Project\solution -> Team1 + Team2 -> TFS2 (???)

What are my options? Is there a tool out there that can do this? Should I use tow different version control packages?

Comment: What do you mean "both teams don't have access"? The correct solution is to *get the other team the access they need*, not try to hack around the problem.

Comment: We don’t own TFS1, so we can’t get both team on one server.

Comment: If you don't own TFS1 why would you ever want your source code to end up there? If this is a vendor then you should dictate that that they use your TFS instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TFS Integration Plataform](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) to sync the Team Projects between the TFS's installs... But the best world is: access one TFS trought TFS Proxy. 
Another way is use Git repository, you will can sync remote the repository with your repository, but access the work items just by TFS.

Comment: That will only work for Get's as for checkin you must go directly to the original TFS. So Proxy will not work... The TFS Integration Tools also have downsides.

Comment: The best answer is to allow communication for all developers to single TFS instance. Have you considered VSO? Http://tfs.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 0):

There are really three ways to solve your problem. The reality is that only #1 is effective if you can't use the cloud. Note that using #3 is fraught with pain and suffering. Aa with all dark side hack/workarounds nothing meets the needs like solving the underlying problem rather than sweeping it under the carpet.

1. All access - the only really viable solution I to give all required users access to the TFS Server. I have worked with healthcare, banking, defence, and even Insurance. In all cases, in all companies, you can have a single server where all required users can access. In some cases it is hard and fraught with beurocracy but ultimately it can be done.
2. Visual Studio Online - while there is fear of the cloud this is likely your only option if you have externals that really can't directly access your network. This would be that common server. If you are in Europe then MS has just signed an agreement that ostensibly puts EU located servers for an American company outside of the reach of the Partiot Act (untested.) You can also easily use the TFS Integration Tools to create a one way sync between VSO and your local server.
3. Bi-directional synchronization - this can be achieved in many ways but there is always a penalty in merging if you have changes on both ends. You can use the TFS Integration Tools that are free or use a Commercially available tool like OpsHub. If your are using Git as your repository within TFS then you can use the command line to push source between two servers... Even if the can't communicate by using a USB stick.

Use #1 or #2 and only as a temporary and short term measure ever use #3
 I use the tools all the time to move **one way only** from one system to another and even this a is a complicated experience. To move stuff bi-directionally you will need a full time resource to resolve conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

If the servers can communicate with each other you may be able to use a system (akin to) replication. There is one master Tfs instance and then external sites use a proxy to allow the second team to work without direct or always-available access to the main server.

Alternatively you may be able to use branches - you could keep a branch for the external team's code and then merge to or from that branch to your mainline. In this scheme you would be able to sync the code by copying between the branch and external site, so you could even transfer updates on memory sticks if there is no direct net connection. Each sync would be pretty time consuming though, as someone on your main server team would have to merge code back and forth through the branch.

Another thing to consider is whether there is any way you can divide up the codebase and the tasks to minimise the overlap between the two teams. for example if one team provides a library that the other uses. This is just too minimise the merging needed.

Comment: How are you intending to do replication? SQL server replication is NOT supported.

Comment: @MrHinsh: "Replication" is not technically correct, but it is a term often associated with remote access to servers (databases and source control), and appears a lot in searches on this subject. As I said, the actual functionality is achieved using a TFS proxy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248710.aspx

Comment: I would disagree :) just because people are using the term incorrectly and inconsistently does not mean that one should copy them. However proxy server's will NOT work in this case. Proxy servers are read-only and you always write back to the main TFS. In addition it only supports source and not Build, Work Items or test management.